# Summing computed values in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to sum the total cost for a given set of items. Each item has a total cost which is price * quantity. This is computing fine. However, I'm now trying to sum up the total cost of all of the items.

Considering all of the item totals are computed individually, how can I sum them all up? Is this done in the viewModel, model, or outside of both?

Here is the code in a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/B9rAt/3/ .As it stands, the total will not display. If you remove the "* quantity" bit in the total it will show, but that's only the sum of the item price, not the item's total.

```
function ItemEntry(ID, inventory, price) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ID;
    self.inventory = inventory;
    self.price = price;

    self.selectedQuantity = ko.observable(); //returned value (trying to get it at least!)

    self.itemTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.price;
        var quantity = self.selectedQuantity();
        var total = price * quantity; 
        return total ? "$" + total.toFixed(2) : "None";
    });


    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
    });
}

function EntryViewModel(newItem) {
    var self = this;
    self.newItem = newItem;


    //start the array with some items
    self.itemNumbers = ko.observableArray([
        new ItemEntry("1", 3, 4.99) //ID, inventory, price 
,new ItemEntry("6", 2, 10.00) //ID, inventory, price 
    ]);

   //Compute total cost here
   self.totalCost = ko.computed(function() {
       var total = 0;
       var quantity = self.selectedQuantity();
        for (var i = 0; i < self.itemNumbers().length; i++) {
            total += Number(self.itemNumbers()[i].price * quantity);
        }
       return total;
    });    

    self.removeItem = function(item) { self.itemNumbers.remove(item) }
}

//populate the select list with values up to the number in inventory (ex, if inventory is 3, it will fill with 0-7)
ko.bindingHandlers.quantityDropdown = {
    init: function(quantityDropdown, inventory, EntryViewModel) {
        var quantity = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(inventory());
        for(var i = 1; i <= quantity; i++){
            $(quantityDropdown).append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }
    }
};



ko.applyBindings(new EntryViewModel());
```

Comment: Having a `selectedQuantity` on the `EntryViewModel` makes no sense. In your `totalCost` you need to calculate with the `self.itemNumbers()[i].selectedQuantity()` http://jsfiddle.net/FvHDr/

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't quite sure how to approach it. I don't have much experience with knockout so I appreciate it.